# colspan wont work when table floating left

Tags: css, html-table

I would like to have a colspan in my table which have this css.

```
 tr { display: block; float: left; }
 th, td { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

I have tried colspan and rowspan but it only cover 1 column what ever value i give it.

here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/proabid/04rebu95/2/

Comment: What do you need the `float:left` and `display:block` for?

Comment: @CarlJan I want each column(th) to show  its properties(td) under it.

Comment: Why not put the `<th>` in the `<thead>` instead of inside the `<tr>`? You can achieve the same result in the fiddle without using `display:block` and `float:left`

Comment: @CarlJan I tried to do as you said but it does not work. Please, change my fiddle and show me how, maybe add a colspan if possible.

Comment: If you post a drawing showing the wanted result me might be able to both understand and help

Answer (score 1):

Here

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background-color: gray;
}
th, td {border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Table header</th>
    <th>Table header</th>
    <th>Table header</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. That is not what I am looking for. I want my data to be displayed vertically. so first row would me 1 1 1, not 1 2 3 and so on.

Comment: I see, you will display from left to right instead of from top to bottom?